# Running multiple jquery datepicker on a page

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Basically, I have a page,which multiple date picker can be added on button click
but however after making a duplicate of the field via JavaScript date picker wont work, it will only work for the first one.
any help will be appreciated 
below is the javascript i used for the datepicker

```
<script language="javascript">

$(function() {
$('.datepicker-input').datepicker({ dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});

});
</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: could you show how are you "making a duplicate of the field via JavaScript"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the datepicker after you've cloned/added it dynamically. For example.

```
var datepicker = $('.datepicker-input:last').clone(); // whatever code you use to dynamically add the datepicker field
datepicker.datepicker({ dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});
```

The code you're using only initializes the available datepicker fields that currently exist, not any future ones that might be added dynamically. I don't believe datepicker supports live events.

Comment: thanks guys, i will try it out @andreas i think i am going to find the jsfiddle link you provided useful